# How to make changes to .config files in the Installation folder using Wix?

Tags: wix, wix3.8

I'm using WiX to create an installer for my application. There are some config files which I need to edit AFTER they are installed on the target system based on values entered by the user during installation. I'm using HEAT command to harvest all the files that need to be installed on the target machine to avoid describing all the files and directories manually. I'm also able to change the configuration of the config files using xml:Util element. Although, I have RECREATE the entire folder structure again to make those changes. Is there a way these changes can be made without having to create the folder structure ?

Basically,

```
TARGETSYSTEM ---> INSTALLFOLDER ---> Dir1
                                |---> Dir2---> SubDir1
                                         |--->SubDir2 ----> file.config



     <File Id="log4netCONFG" Source="WHATSHOULDCOMEHERE?/file.config" KeyPath="yes" />
        <util:XmlFile Id="UpdateLogFileAppenderFilePath"
                  File="[#log4netCONFG]"
                  Action="setValue"
                  ElementPath="//appender[\[]@name='LogFileAppender'[\]]/param[\    []@name='File'[\]]"
                  Name="value"
                  Value="[LOGFILEAPPENDERFILEPATH]"/>
```